# how to kill and execute app in memu virtual machine (scheduled restart)

Tags: virtual-machine, scheduler, restart

I read the documentation but, I've got no idea how can I kill process and execute a specific app in MEmu virtual machine

http://www.memuplay.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/MEmu-Command-Line-Management-Interface-Version-4.3.20_OSE.pdf

Have You got any idea how can do that from command line?

I also tried with BlueStack, but BlueStack rebooting by a long time, and doesn't work from scheduler (I tried with *.bat and *.ps1)

In simply words I need to restart Android app on virtual machine in schedule :)

Best Regards

Answer (score -1):

You can make autostart of Memu with your specific app and then restart Memu itself(at shleduler or not)